# Can I find a power series representation for $\frac {1}{(1+x)^2}$ ONLY by differentiating $\frac {1}{1+x}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

There are probably much easier to find the power series for $\frac {1}{(1+x)^2}$ than by differentiating $\frac {1}{1/1+x}$, but I think it should be possible. I've gotten extremely close, but my final answer is just a tiny bit different. Here's what I did:

Note that I use the fact that $\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n$

Firstly, $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1+x} $$

Now, using that, I find the power series representation for $\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$:

$$\frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1+x} = \frac{d}{dx} \frac{1}{1-(-x)} = \frac{d}{dx} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(x)^n = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{d}{dx} (-1)^n(x)^n =  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nn(x)^{n-1} $$

So my final answer is $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nn(x)^{n-1} = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

But apparently the correct answer is: $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)(x)^{n} = \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}$$

If anyone could point out my mistake and show me how the latter answer is arrived at I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: You missed a sign in that $\frac{d}{dx}\frac1{1+x}=-\frac1{(1+x)^2}$

Comment: Your sum has an awkward term at $n=0$ (there shouldn't be a $\frac 1x$ term...even with a $0$ coefficient.  The first non-zero term, at $n=1$ gives $-1$ so your expression is clearly not correct.  That said, it differs from the other only in the sign.

Comment: $$\frac{1}{(1+x)^2}=(-1)\cdot \frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{1+x}.$$ You are missing a sign.

Comment: I already stated that @ThomasAndrews

Comment: Your strategy is fine (as is Marty Cohen's of using a Cauchy product); you just need a little more practice with the way differentiation affects the indices in power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly
$$\frac{d}{dx}\frac1{1+x}=-\frac1{(1+x)^2}$$
so we have that
$$\begin{align}
\frac1{(1+x)^2}
&=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^nn(x)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}n(x)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}n(x)^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+2}(n+1)(x)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n(n+1)(x)^n\\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I get lost between the third and fourth equalities though: why does $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}n(x)^{n-1} =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}n(x)^{n-1}$? Why does the expression inside not change? Wouldn't shifting the index $n$ by $1$ have an affect on the expression inside (such as the expression becoming $(-1)^{n+2}n(x)^{n}$)?

Comment: The initial term is $0$ because of the factor of $n$, so it can be removed leaving every other term the same.

Comment: Ohh I see. Everything makes sense now, immense thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply.

Since
$\dfrac1{1-x}
=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n
$,

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac1{(1-x)^2}
&=(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n)(\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^m)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} x^{m+n}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{m=0}^{k} x^{k}
\qquad k=m+n, n=k-m\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k\sum_{m=0}^{k}1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)x^k\\
\text{then}\\
\dfrac1{(1+x)^2}
&=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(k+1)(-1)^kx^k\\
\end{array}
$